# Difference of New Function and Uninitialized Variable

Tags: go

What's the difference of new function and uninitialized variable? What's the advantage of both?

```
s := new(string) // *string
var s *string    // *string
var s string     // string
```

Is it only for simplicity the code? Because i think it's same

```
s := new(string) /* same as */ var s *string = &emptyString
```

Comment: new allocates memory dynamically, for uninitialized variable memory is not allocated yet.

Comment: is it address of memory or content of memory? because if I check address of both, they are allocates. The content also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first difference:

> The built-in function new takes a type T, allocates storage for a
>   variable of that type **at run time**

2nd difference: 
`new` initializes allocated string to empty string ("") and initializes pointer to the address of this string, but `var ptr2 *string` 
just initializes `ptr2` to `nil` and do not allocates any string:

sample code A (with commented output):

```
ptr := new(string)               // *ptr has value "", ptr: static type *string
fmt.Println(len(*ptr))           // 0
fmt.Println(cap([]byte(*ptr)))   // 32
fmt.Printf("%T %q\n", ptr, *ptr) // *string ""
```

sample code B (with commented output):

```
var ptr2 *string                // ptr2 has value nil, static type *string
fmt.Printf("%T %#[1]v\n", ptr2) // *string (*string)(nil)
//fmt.Println(len(*ptr2)) // panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
//fmt.Println(cap([]byte(*ptr2)))
```

sample code C (with commented output):

```
var str string                // str has value "", static type string
fmt.Println(len(str))         // 0
fmt.Println(cap([]byte(str))) // 32
fmt.Printf("%T %[1]q\n", str) // string ""
```

Allocation:

> **The built-in function new takes a type T, allocates storage for a
>   variable of that   type at run time**, and returns a value of type *T
>   pointing to it. The variable is initialized as described in the
>   section on [initial values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).
>
> ```
> new(T)
> ```
>
> For instance
>
> ```
> type S struct { a int; b float64 }
> new(S)
> ```
>
> allocates storage for a variable of type S, initializes it (a=0,
>   b=0.0), and returns a value of type *S containing the address of the
>   location.

ref: https://golang.org/ref/spec

Allocation with new:

> Go has two allocation primitives, the built-in
>   functions new and make. They do different things and apply to
>   different types, which can be confusing, but the rules are simple.
>   Let's talk about new first. **It's a built-in function that allocates
>   memory**, but unlike its namesakes in some other languages it does not
>   initialize the memory, it only zeros it. That is, new(T) allocates
>   zeroed storage for a new item of type T and returns its address, a
>   value of type *T. In Go terminology, it returns a pointer to a newly
>   allocated zero value of type T.
>
> **Since the memory returned by new is zeroed, it's helpful to arrange
>   when designing your data structures that the zero value of each type
>   can be used without further initialization.** This means a user of the
>   data structure can create one with new and get right to work. For
>   example, the documentation for bytes.Buffer states that "the zero
>   value for Buffer is an empty buffer ready to use." Similarly,
>   sync.Mutex does not have an explicit constructor or Init method.
>   Instead, the zero value for a sync.Mutex is defined to be an unlocked
>   mutex.
>
> The zero-value-is-useful property works transitively. Consider this
>   type declaration.
>
> ```
> type SyncedBuffer struct {
>     lock    sync.Mutex
>     buffer  bytes.Buffer
> } Values of type SyncedBuffer are also ready to use immediately upon allocation or just declaration. In the next snippet, both p and v
> ```
>
> will work correctly without further arrangement:
>
> ```
> p := new(SyncedBuffer)  // type *SyncedBuffer
> var v SyncedBuffer      // type  SyncedBuffer
> ```
>
> Allocation with make:   Back to allocation. The built-in function
>   make(T, args) serves a purpose different from new(T). It creates
>   slices, maps, and channels only, and it returns an initialized (not
>   zeroed) value of type T (not *T). The reason for the distinction is
>   that these three types represent, under the covers, references to data
>   structures that must be initialized before use. A slice, for example,
>   is a three-item descriptor containing a pointer to the data (inside an
>   array), the length, and the capacity, and until those items are
>   initialized, the slice is nil. For slices, maps, and channels, make
>   initializes the internal data structure and prepares the value for
>   use. For instance,
>
> ```
> make([]int, 10, 100)
> ```
>
> allocates an array of 100 ints and then creates a slice structure with
>   length 10 and a capacity of 100
>   pointing at the first 10 elements of the array. (When making a slice,
>   the capacity can be omitted; see the section on slices for more
>   information.) **In contrast, new([]int) returns a pointer to a newly
>   allocated, zeroed slice structure, that is, a pointer to a nil slice
>   value. These examples illustrate the difference between new and make:**
>
> ```
> var p *[]int = new([]int)       // allocates slice structure; *p == nil; rarely useful
> var v  []int = make([]int, 100) // the slice v now refers to a new array of 100 ints
>
> // Unnecessarily complex:
> var p *[]int = new([]int)
> *p = make([]int, 100, 100)
>
> // Idiomatic:
> v := make([]int, 100)
> ```
>
> Remember that make applies only to maps, slices and channels and does
>   not return a pointer. To obtain an explicit pointer allocate with new
>   or take the address of a variable explicitly.

ref:  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Comment: So the conclusion is var s *string = &emptyString same with s := new(string)?

Comment: Correction: `new()` allocates memory for a value, not a variable. In `s := new(string)`, the variable is "s", and the value it holds is a pointer to another value -- this time a string, -- which was allocated by `new()`.

Comment: @Amd: When var allocates memory? At Compile? -- Sorry a little bit OOT, what is the difference allocates memory at run time and compile? Beside of the time.

Comment: To be more clear: variables are named things holding values. They are for the programmer only. What's kept in memory, are values. So "allocating a variable" simply is nonsense because you can only allocate a value. Note that this is only true for  static compiled languages; in certain (most?) dynamic/scripting languages it's indeed possible to create variables at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
var s *string
```

Simply declare "s" as a pointer to a string. In this case "s" is a nil pointer, this is the default value in golang for pointers.

This code:

```
s := new(string)
```

Also declare "s" as a pointer to a string, but this time the string is initialized. That means "s" is a non-nil pointer, and points to the default value for string in golang, an empty string.

[See this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/r8AbKlKQZI)

Comment: So the conclusion is var s *string = &emptyString same with s := new(string)?

Comment: Yes. Just the former form is supported only for `struct` types. But *conceptually* they are the same. I'm also pretty sure the compiler would end up generating the same code for them.